# Algorithm to filter data structure AND/OR/NOT (similar to GraphQL implementation)

Tags: algorithm, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to implement a data structure that allows for powerful filtering within my application.

The closest implementation I've found is from Prisma https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.27/prisma-graphql-api/reference/queries-qwe1/#combining-multiple-filters (which is actually from GraphQL specification, for what I understand)

Example:

```
{
  OR: [
    {
      AND: [
        { title_in: ["My biggest Adventure", "My latest Hobbies"] }
        { published: true }
      ]
    }
    { id: "cixnen24p33lo0143bexvr52n" }
  ]
}
```

The idea is to compare a context against the filters and see if it's a match.

In the above example, the "context" would be an object with the `id`, `title` and `published` fields.

I'm looking for an algorithm that would perform the comparison and resolve whether it's a match or not.

As I'm not looking at reinventing the wheel (especially that it's a complex algorithm IMHO, as AND/OR/NOT conditions can be nested), I wonder if that particular algorithm already exists, or is based on some standards *(as we can find that particular data structure on several apps, such as Prisma, PipeDrive and other)*.

I'm looking for documentation, implementation examples or even open source implementations. (I'm using JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldn't find a solution that matched our requirements, so built our own and released it as OSS (MIT).

https://github.com/UnlyEd/conditions-matcher

> Compares a given context with a filter (a set of conditions) and resolves whether the context validates the filter. Strongly inspired by GraphQL filters.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for such an implementation but couldn't find one.

So I created a prototype for it: https://github.com/Errorname/logical-object-match

Comment: Awesome! We also started to work on our own implementation, it's not open source yet (I'm reviewing it right now) but I can see both are similar, yet don't offer the same capabilities. We'll try to release ours soon in open source so we can compare!